# Vuejs return data from .js file

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue and am working on an app to get the weather from a weather api.
The code below works if I leave `axios.get()` in `Content.vue` as it is below.
I want to move it to a separate file (`WeatherAPI.js`) and call it from there.  If I comment out `axois.get()` call in `Content.vue` and uncomment `this.todaysWeather = WeatherAPI.returnTodaysWeather();` it doesn't work.  I do see the data logged to the console from `WeatherAPI.js` so it's getting it, but it doesn't seem to return it correctly.  I see `undefined` in the console log from `Content.vue`.

Content.vue

```
<template>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row answerRow text-center">
        <div class="col">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <weather-today :todaysWeather="todaysWeather"></weather-today>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Column2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Today from '../weather/Today.vue'
import WeatherAPI from '../data/WeatherAPI.js'
import axios from 'axios'
const apiURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
const apiKey = "MyKeyHere";
const zipCode = "11111,us";
const dailyWeatherUrl = apiURL + "?zip=" + zipCode + "&appid=" + apiKey;
export default {
    mounted(){
        this.getTodaysWeather();
        console.log(this.todaysWeather)
    },
    data () {
        return {
            todaysWeather: {name: "testname"}
        }
    },
    components: {
        'weather-today': Today
    },
    methods: {
        getTodaysWeather () {
            //this.todaysWeather = WeatherAPI.returnTodaysWeather();            
            axios.get(dailyWeatherUrl)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    this.todaysWeather = response.data;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });


        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
.answerRow{
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

Today.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container row1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Todays Weather</h2>
            </div>
        </div>            
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                City: {{ todaysWeather.name }}
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import WeatherAPI from '../data/WeatherAPI.js'
export default {
    props: ['todaysWeather'],
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.todaysWeather)
    }    
}
</script>

<style>
.row1{
    background-color: #3498DB;
}
</style>
```

WeatherAPI.js

```
const apiURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
const apiKey = "MyKeyHere";
const zipCode = "11111,us";
const dailyWeatherUrl = apiURL + "?zip=" + zipCode + "&appid=" + apiKey;

import axios from 'axios';
export default {   
  data(){
    return {
      todaysWeather: {}
    }
  },
    returnTodaysWeather () {
        axios.get(dailyWeatherUrl)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.todaysWeather = response.data;
          console.log(this.todaysWeather);
          return this.todaysWeather;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `WeatherAPI.js` file really shouldn't have anything to do with Vue, it should just be a file that contains methods that interact with the weather API.

**WeatherAPI.js**

```
const apiURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
const apiKey = "MyKeyHere";
const zipCode = "11111,us";
const dailyWeatherUrl = apiURL + "?zip=" + zipCode + "&appid=" + apiKey;

import axios from 'axios';

export function returnTodaysWeather () {
  return axios.get(dailyWeatherUrl)
           .then(response => response.data)
}
```

Notice that this function returns a promise. We will use that later. Also, this code exports the function directly. If you wanted to, you could export an object that has multiple functions interacting with the API in different ways.

Now in `Content.vue` all you need to do is import the weather API you want to use.

**Content.vue**

```
// import the returnTodaysWeather function from the api file
import { returnTodaysWeather } from '../data/WeatherAPI.js'

export default {
    mounted(){
        this.getTodaysWeather();
        console.log(this.todaysWeather)
    },
    data () {
        return {
            todaysWeather: {name: "testname"}
        }
    },
    components: {
        'weather-today': Today
    },
    methods: {
        getTodaysWeather () {
            // The API returns a promise. In the callback from the 
            // promise, we can set the Vue's data with the results
            // of the call to the API
            returnTodaysWeather().then(weather => this.todaysWeather = weather)           
        }
    }
}
```

I removed the error handling, but in production you would obviously want to `catch` errors from the API.